# which privileges should I grant to run the query below in a postgresql instance

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I faced a task: find out minimal user permissions that I should grant to run a query:

```
select grantee, routine_name from information_schema.routine_privileges where routine_name in ('pg_read_file', 'pg_read_binary_file') group by grantee, routine_name;
```

I tried to grant

```
GRANT SELECT ON information_schema.routine_privileges TO <test_user>;
```

and I failed to get any result

If I run the query under the postgres user - I get all grantees corresponding routine_name

But what should I do to get those records under the test_user account ?

P.S.
A remark: as I understood the information_schema.routine_privileges is  a view:

so I granted a SELECT  on tables: pg_proc, pg_namespace and pg_authid to my test_user

but still was unsuccesfull

P.P.S. It seems to me I have to troubleshoot: find out an object the user has insufficient access rights.. But how to find theese objects?

Answer (score 0):

You can only see routines in `information_schema.routine_privileges` if you are a member of the grantor or grantee roles or if `EXECUTE` was granted to `PUBLIC`.

Answer (score -2):

@Laurenz Albe

Ah... I believe I understood. Thank You.

here is an example of a result of the select query
I ran thje query under postgres account
But there is another account (tst_usr_3) in my test PostgreSQL instance. And when I run the select query under the tst_usr_3 account - I get nothing.
If I GRANT EXECUTE ON pg_read_binary_file to tst_usr_3 - and then I run the select query - I get result just upon tst_usr_3. But I cannot see any data upon the tst_usr2.
So IF I understand right - I must grant role tst_usr_3 to tst_usr2 - then I will be able to see routines of tst_usr2. Correct?

[image: pg_read_binary_file_query_with_sa_example]

In bottom line the point of my question: how to get all roles being grunted to execute pg_read_file / pg_read_binary_file? Paying attention that I'm allowed to use an account without administrator role within the PostgreSQL instance. What permissions should I grant? I'm affraid it's forbiden to grant a user role to another user role..

But what if I use the SECURITY DEFINER clause to create a function that runs with the privileges of the sysadmin? Would It help?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.  Please construct your questions based on the details in [mcve].   Adding table DDL statements, sample DML statements, and providing desired output via a markup table as shown in the example makes it easier for us to provide great answers.

Comment: I do not have a new question. I tried to add details that as I thought would clarify the problem I faced. But thank You for lowering my reputation. Wish  good health to You.

Comment: If you want to clarify your question, you can do that by editing the question. Clarifications do not belong in an "answer", which are for *answers* to the question only. When you delete your answer, the points you lost will be returned.